# SVN - error on all operations from Windows machine

Tags: windows, connection, svn

I've been using SVN for a while on different machines: Mac, Linux and Windows, and everything was fine, but suddenly it began failing on Windows maching, while working on Linux and Mac.

Here is an error that I'm getting on all the operations (update, commit)

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://www.server.com/repo': Could not read status line: 
connection was closed by server (https://www.server.com)
```

I dont remember installing anything network aggressive recently, disabling firewall and antivirus doesn't help.

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

On SO, someone suggests that this is a http versus a https problem.

Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613149/svn-could-not-read-status-line-connection-was-closed-by-server